# Finding optimal BST to minimize lookup cost

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to figure out how to create an optimal BST to minimize lookup costs for elements.

Assume that the cost to look up an element is (1 + distance from root).
So the cost for the root will be 1, and the cost of elements at depth 1 will be 2 etc.

Lets say I have `n` integer elements: x1, x2, ... , xn

And lets say x1 < x2 < ... < xn

And lets say the following happens:

> x1 is accessed 2 times
>
> x2 is accessed 4 times
>
> x3 is accessed 3 times
>
> x4 is accessed 6 times

This can be represented in an array like [2, 4, 3, 6]

For this case, I think the optimal BST is

[Link to image because I'm not allowed to embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiWpP.png)

The total cost here is 29.

Can there be a BST that minimizes the cost even further?

And does there exist an algorithm that, given elements and the number of times they're accessed, is able to generate an optimal BST?

Comment: Have you searched SO for [optimal BSTs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Optimal+binary+search+tree)? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree), you can use Knuth's algorithm to get the optimal BST in `O(n^2)`, or Mehlhorn's approximative algorithm to get an almost optimal BST in `O(n)`.

Comment: If you know what the keys are, and can afford to build an optimal BST, then why not just create a dictionary or even a [minimal perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function)?